# Is this the case of mixed conditionals?

Tags: conditionals

The situation is as follows: I was waiting for my friend Kate to visit me. It was time for her to come but she still didn't show up. When I called her, she replied that she had a meeting right at that moment. Then she asked me, "Did you forget about it?" I realized that I completely forgot about it. And I wanted to answer in a kind of sarcastic funny way. So I said, "If I did (remembered), I wouldn't have called you NOW".

Was my reply grammatically correct?  Or I should have said, "If I had remembered, I wouldn't have called you now" instead? If both sentences are not correct, what would be a better way to reply?

Comment: Not what you asked, but "she had a meeting" could be "we were supposed to meet".

Comment: Thanks! Does it ("she had a meeting") sound too official or just wrong?

Comment: It sounds as though Kate was being cute: "she had a meeting" could mean a meeting with *someone else* but she then reveals it was supposed to be with you.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer would have been "If I had remembered, I wouldn't have called you now."